# Django admin action for items selected over several pages

Tags: python, django

I want to perform an action based on selection of items spanning over several pages. Just how can this be achieved. I saw this post to create tags, but it is not so comfortable for my requirement. http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/. I should be able to perhaps keep on appending to a list as 1 action. Then perform the main action once this list is ready. Is there a better solution. Using django 1.6.5

Comment: Do you mean to mark all items and run an acction on them? On django 1.7  the selection of all elements is possbile by 2 clicks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3091263/ger-s-brett I don't want all elements I want to select only few spanning multiple pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default list per page is 100, I have changed it to 1000 using the parameter in the model admin:

```
list_per_page = 1000
```